# Como criar uma lista e colocar outras listas dentro?

Tags: python, lista, arquivo

```
def annexsentence():
        nome_tarefa=input("Nome da Tarefa :")
        data_atual = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
        data_final=input("Data Final :")
        estado="Aberta"
        lista=[nome_tarefa,str(data_atual),str(data_final),estado]
        annexsentence=open("ficheiro2.txt","a")
        annexsentence.write(str(lista)+"\n")
        annexsentence.close()
    annexsentence()
```

Boa noite, gostaria de saber como colocar esta lista que criei já dentro de outra lista ficando por exemplo:

```
[[lista1,lista1,lista1,],[lista2,lista2,lista2,],[lista3,lista3,lista3,]]
```

para poder estar sempre a acrescentar uma nova lista dentro da mesma

Comment: A variável `lista` é a da segunda dimensão certo? E qual é a lista da primeira dimensão? Cada dimensão é um nível, uma dimensão: `[1,2,3]`, duas dimensões: `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`, ...

Comment: eu quero criar uma lista vazia por exemplo lista=[] e dentro da lista colocar uma 2 lista com por exemplo o [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3] para ficar [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

Comment: @PedroPinheiro As soluções da pergunta **devem** estar na área de respostas, não na pergunta em si. Se conseguiu resolver o problema de uma forma diferente das já abordadas nas respostas, sinta-se livre em [responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/5878).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta criar uma variável do tipo `list` e passar uma lista no método `append`:

```
lista = []
lista.append([1,2,3])
lista.append([1,2,3])
lista.append([1,2,3])
print lista
#[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Você pode criar uma função para alimentar a lista e outra para salva-lá, sendo que só irá chamar a função que salva após ter preenchido totalmente a lista:

```
lista = []

def annexsentence():
    nome_tarefa=input("Nome da Tarefa :")
    data_atual = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    data_final=input("Data Final :")
    estado="Aberta"
    lista.append([nome_tarefa,str(data_atual),str(data_final),estado])

def salvar():
    annexsentence=open("ficheiro2.txt","a")
    annexsentence.write(str(lista)+"\n")
    annexsentence.close()
```

Ou você pode sobreescrever o conteúdo do arquivo:

```
lista=[]

def annexsentence():
    nome_tarefa=input("Nome da Tarefa :")
    data_atual = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    data_final=input("Data Final :")
    estado="Aberta"
    lista.append([nome_tarefa,str(data_atual),str(data_final),estado])
    annexsentence=open("ficheiro2.txt","w")
    annexsentence.write(str(lista)+"\n")
    annexsentence.close()
```

Comment: Ja tentei fazer isso mas depois no ficheiro fica assim [['1', '01-01-19', '1', 'Aberta']][['1', '01-01-19', '1', 'Aberta']] e não fica como eu quero nem com as virgulas supostamente deveria ficar [['1', '01-01-19', '1', 'Aberta'] ,['1', '01-01-19', '1', 'Aberta']]

Comment: Você deve escrever no arquivo apenas depois de ter a lista pronta, do jeito que fez você escreve a cada sublista, editei a resposta